# how to start from within my shell-script xterm which starts mplayer and plays the files that are the argument of the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mplayer

What I want to do: Start my script with a list of files as arguments. From within my script I want to start xterm that starts mplayer with these files.

I tried several things. **I call my script like this:**

```
myscript.sh *
```

The **files are named like**

```
"aaa AAA"
"bbb BBB"
"ccc DDD"
```

(i.e. filenames with spaces) and are playable sounds, music or videos with mplayer.

### This is what I tried

All of the following commands were written **inside my script!**

I tried:

1. The following **works**. Files are printed.

   ```
   ls -l $@
   ```
2. The following **works**. Files are printed.

   ```
   IFS='\n'
   ls -l $*
   ```
3. The following **works**. Files are printed. Strangely I do not need the `IFS='\n'` here. Why?

   ```
   xterm -e 'ls -l $*; read'
   ```
4. This **does not** find the files.

   ```
   FILES=$@
   ls -l $FILES
   ```
5. This **does not** find the files. Here all filenames are treated as one long filename. (???)

   ```
   IFS='\n'
   FILES=$@
   ls -l $FILES
   ```
6. This **does not** find the files.

   ```
   export FILES=$@
   ls -l $FILES
   ```
7. But the following **works**. Files are printed.

   ```
   IFS='\n'
   export FILES=$@
   ls -l $FILES
   ```

---

Now with mplayer.

1. This **works**.

   ```
   IFS='\n'
   export FILES=$@
   mplayer $FILES
   ```
2. This **does not** work. But why does number 2 for `ls -l` work then? Here mplayer exits printing it’s help as if I just start `mplayer` with no arguments.

   ```
   xterm -e 'mplayer $*; read'
   ```
3. This **does not** work. It fails for all the files with spaces in the filename.

   ```
   IFS='\n'
   FILES=$@
   xterm -e 'mplayer $FILES; read'
   ```

**Question:** How can I start mplayer from its own xterm with the files saved in the `$FILES` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the arguments to your script to mplayer, in an xterm, this should work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e mplayer "$@"
```

This works because of how `"$@"` expands: one parameter per item. `xterm` does *not* attempt to interpret the arguments to the command in any way; it just passes them through.

If you need actually put your file list in a variable, your best bet is to use an array variable. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a FILES
for f; do
    if [ -r "$f" ]; then
        FILES+=("$f")
    fi
done

xterm -e mplayer "${FILES[@]}"
```

The above filters the files to only pass ones which are readable. This is just an example, normally you'd not do this type of filtering. Also, typically, I'd use a lowercase variable name, unless I were planning on exporting it.

PS: Depending on what you're doing, are you aware of mplayer's `-slave` mode?